# How do I enable drag after being drop by using jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Drag is not working after dropping on the area. I have used Jquery UI for this. How do I re drag the buttons? I dont want to to stick it in a particular position so that i can reposition it any where on the board.

Here is the link http://www.onlinedemowebsite.com/design/swatch/drag-and-drop/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     for (var i = 1; i <= 225; i++) {
         $('.board').append($('<div/>',{id:"cell_"+i}));
    }
     $('.board div').addClass('cellBox');
     $('.board .cellBox').append('<span>Drop</span>');

     $(".letters").draggable({
            revert: true,
            snap:true,
            snap: '.cellBox', snapMode: 'inner', snapTolerance:40,
      });

    $( ".board" ).droppable({
         activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
         hoverClass: 'ui-state-active', 

         over: function(event, ui) {
             $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('lettersBig');
         },
          out: function(event, ui) {
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('lettersBig');
         },
         drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('onCell');
            $(ui.draggable).draggable('enable');

            if (ui.draggable.is('.letters')) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('span').html('got!');
            // cloning and appending prevents the revert animation from still occurring
            ui.draggable.clone(true).css({position:relative,top:0,left:0}).appendTo($(this));
            ui.draggable.remove();

             } else {
            $('.cellBox > span').html('No!')
              setTimeout(function(){ $('.cellBox > span').html('Drop'); }, 1000);

           }
        }

    });
```

})

the HTML code is following

```
<div class="container">
<div class="board">
</div>
<!--/board-->

<div class="lettersContainer">
    <div class="letters">
        <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <!--/letters-->

    <div class="letters correct">
        <span>X</span>
    </div>
    <!--/letters-->

    <div class="letters">
        <span>M</span>
    </div>
    <!--/letters-->
</div>
<!--/lettersContainer-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not making the item draggable after dropping and appending

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('onCell');
        $(ui.draggable).draggable({
            revert: true,
            snap:true,
            snap: '.cellBox', snapMode: 'inner', snapTolerance:40,
        });

        if (ui.draggable.is('.letters')) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('span').html('got!');
        // cloning and appending prevents the revert animation from still occurring
        ui.draggable.clone(true).css({position:relative,top:0,left:0}).appendTo($(this));
        ui.draggable.remove();

         } else {
        $('.cellBox > span').html('No!')
          setTimeout(function(){ $('.cellBox > span').html('Drop'); }, 1000);

       }
    }
```

//edited

```
$( ".board" ).droppable({
         activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
         hoverClass: 'ui-state-active', 

         over: function(event, ui) {
             $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('lettersBig');
         },
          out: function(event, ui) {
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('lettersBig');
         },
         drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('onCell');
            $(ui.draggable).draggable('destroy');

            if (ui.draggable.is('.letters')) {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight').find('.cellBox').html('got!');
            // cloning and appending prevents the revert animation from still occurring
            var objectClone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            $(objectClone).css('position','relative').position({top:0,left:0});
            $(objectClone).draggable({
                revert: true,
                snap:true,
                snap: '.cellBox', snapMode: 'inner', snapTolerance:40,
            });
            $(this).append($(objectClone));
            ui.draggable.remove();

             } else {
            $('.cellBox > span').html('No!')
              setTimeout(function(){ $('.cellBox > span').html('Drop'); }, 1000);

           }
        }

    });
```

i have changed the droppable function a little bit. It has some glitches but try it once and see yourself

Comment: Thanks for your reply . If you you see the code i have try to make it by adding 
$(ui.draggable).draggable('enable');
but it is not working.
can you please suggest how to make it

Comment: @Krishnendu I have made changes to the droppable function. Kindly see to it

Comment: Hi Tejasva,  thanks for your help, I have implemented above code, now I can drag the object.But when I drop on the board it not getting proper position.It goes far left form its actual position. can you say why this is happening ?
Here is the links http://www.onlinedemowebsite.com/design/swatch/drag-and-drop/try2.html
 thanks in advance

Comment: There are two problems regarding this error.
1. position of the lettersContainer
2. positions of the individual letters in the letters container.
You can easily see that the letter 'A' when added to the box just above it shifts to the extreme left of the same row. And when you add 'X' to the same box, it gets added to the box besides 'A', clearly their float property and their relative positions are making this shift.
you can possibly use the position of the ui.draggable and clear these offsets before appending. Or you can make an entirely new object(instead of cloning) and then append.